# SQLite Ordering rules

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-order-by, coalesce

I have a SQLite database in android with some tables, one of them is this:

```
trainings (date TEXT, exercise TEXT, repetitions INTEGER, weight REAL)
```

and it has two indexes in weight and repetitions  both are ASC.

This is the thing, In a select statement with order by repetitions I got something like this:

```
Select * from trainings WHERE exercise='"+exercise+"' AND repetitions != '-' AND repetitions != 0 ORDER BY COALESCE( weight, date);

0
0
0
12
13
25
-
-
```

I want to know if it's possible to put the '-' results at the beggining rather than at the end, because in my app, I treat 0 and '-' as the same thing and I have to get ordering getting this two datas together.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that if I do one select with only the '-' and 0 results and then th select in my question with repetitions !='-' AND repetitions !=0 it may be solved but I think thats not the best way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transform arbitrary values into other arbitrary values, use the [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case); something like this:

```
... ORDER BY
      CASE COALESCE(weight, date)
        WHEN '-' THEN 0
        ELSE          COALESCE(weight, date)
      END
```